What does using - while setting limit type imply? What are its implications
While setting limits for a resource in Linux system, via the limits.conf file, there is a type field. This field can have the following 3 values

"Hard" - The user cannot increase this value.
"Soft" - The user can increase or decrease this value within a permitted range.
"-"

The third option, i.e. - is the one which I need clarity on. The manual say that if the type is "-" then it implies setting both the soft and hard limits together. How is it possible to set hard and soft limit simultaneously?
How does it impact the usage of the resources by the user? For example if the maxlogins is set to a value of 2 and the type is "-" then is the limit enforced strictly or can the user change this?
What is preferred? Putting a hyphen or setting the type to soft or setting the type to hard?
I had to put the list values in double quotes because the hyphen/minus character was being interpreted by the editor as something else.

This question might be similar to hard vs - in limits.conf
